# Prompt user for input after invalid input

Tags: java

So I made a program, and I need to keep prompting for coordinates if the user enters a non-negative, invalid input.  Meaning that if the user enters a number above 2 or a letter it should ask him to choose again.  The problem that I am running into is that right when I enter a letter, the program terminates and I get InputMisMatchException for the letter, and ArrayOutOfBoundsException for the higher numbers.  Is there a way to bypass all those errors and just ask the user to pick again?

So for example:

```
"Enter the coordinates to place an 'X'. Row then Column."
 //enters number > 2 or letter
"Invalid input. Please choose again."
```

Comment: I've found the solution for entering a letter but I can't seem to get the parameter for a number that is out of bounds that also works with the code I currently have.  @Tom

Answer (score 0):

Use a do/while loop:

```
boolean valid = false;
do {
    try {
        // "Enter the coordinates to place an 'X'. Row then Column."
        // validate input
        valid = // final value of validation goes here
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // invalid input
    } while (!valid)
}
```